# Whats wrong with this hover code

Tags: html, css, hover

I made a div, and another div (that's hidden) and made a hover, but it wont show the hidden div if you hover your mouse over the first div... 
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title> Welkom op FreeAppzToday </title>

    <style>


    #home   {background: black; width:6%; height:6%; margin-left: -1%; margin-top: -2.2%}
    #home:hover{background-color: #1A49B4}
    #text-home  {font-size:225%; margin-left: 15%; color: white}
    a   {text-decoration: none;}

        #games  {background: black; width:6%; height:6%; margin-left: 5%; margin-top: -5.1%}
        #text-games     {font-size:250%; margin-left: 1.5%; color: white}
        #games:hover {background-color: #1A49B4}

        #action {background: black; width:6%; height:3%; margin-left: 5%; margin-top: -1.1%;}
        #text-action    {font-size:125%; margin-left: 1.5%; color: white}
        #games:hover,    #action {visibility: visible;}
        #action:hover {background-color: #1A49B4}
        #action     {visibility: hidden;}

</style>


</head>
<body>


<div id='home'><a href='index.php'><p id='text-home' >Home</P></a></div>
<div id='games'> <a href='games/index.php'><p id='text-games'>Games</p></a></div>
<div id='action'><a href='games/action.php'><p id='text-action'> Action</p></a></a>
</div>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You appear to be attempting to do scripting/programming in CSS. That's not going to work. Write some JavaScript. Also, what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: I always use php and html...

Comment: last time I did this it worked

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect

Comment: Quite simply: what you are trying to do can't be done in CSS, the closest is to use the next sibling selector `~`. And if you did it before, what's stopping you from using the same code?

Comment: @LcLk you are wrong, this can be done in CSS, see my answer for a very basic example.

Comment: @Sharky, that's a very specific case where two elements are side by side, you should use the sibling selector instead of adding a wrapper div.

Comment: @EsliStavenga: No it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is @Sharky's answer updated to use the sibling selector `~`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/u1ykptzx/1/)

CSS:

```
p {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
div {
   padding:8px;
}

#action {
   visibility:hidden;
}

#action:hover {
   visibility:visible;
}

#games:hover ~ #action {
   visibility:visible;
}
```

To prevent the `#action` link from hiding once you mouseout from the `#games` link you need to add the same css to the `#action:hover` selector, and as the `p` element inside the link has a margin, I had to remove it and place it on the parent div.

Comment: ah that `<p>` margin! nice :D

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some problems some tags are not closing properly, so i didn't bother with it.

See this very basic example to understand:

http://jsfiddle.net/8mrugaoo/

You will need a container div, that on hover will assign `visibility:visible` to a child element.

```
<div id='home'>
    <a href='index.php'><p id='text-home' >Home</p></a>
</div>

<div id="games_container">
    <div id='games'>
        <a href='games/index.php'><p id='text-games'>Games</p></a>
    </div>
    <div id='action'>
        <a href='games/action.php'><p id='text-action'> Action</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the magic happens here:

```
#action {visibility:hidden;}

#games_container:hover #action {visibility:visible;}
```

Comment: As a side note: `visibility: hidden;` will hide the action link but it will still take up space compared to using `display:none;`

Comment: @LcLk can you post an answer with sibling selector? `#games:hover + #action` will show the hidden, but as soon you hover out of `#games` the sibling dissapears... http://jsfiddle.net/8mrugaoo/1/ how can we make this work without adding a container?